# Android : Is it possible to show jquery or javascript popup?

Tags: android, jquery, popup

is it possible to show jquery or javascript popup message in android WebView ?

Comment: Have you tried just putting an `alert()`?

Comment: Yes,  I tried but nothing happens  ..

Answer (score 1):

You can display popup message with the JavaScript `alert()`, `confirm()`, or `prompt()`. If they are not working then something else is wrong. Ensure your JavaScript is properly reaching those statements. Use `console.log()` to write messages to LogCat to trace your execution.  Also make sure JavaScript is enabled.  IE:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the line given below to show a alert in webview:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello Android');");
```

If you want to make some changes in UI you can call javascript like given below in overridden function onPageFinished()

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
super.onPageFinished(view, url);

   wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('client').style.visibility ='hidden';");

   }
}
```